Pandas conditional grouping
I have a set of data, where a user action generates multiple events.
A configuration event, that logs the amount of each product used and then for each used product, an available event. These events may not be received in order and sometimes with a little delay.



Timestamp
Event
Data




25/07/2024  08:58:49
Configuration
A,B


25/07/2024  08:58:49
Product Available
A,1


25/07/2024  08:58:51
Product Available
B,3


25/07/2024  10:17:53
Product Available
B,1


25/07/2024  10:17:53
Configuration
B,C


25/07/2024  10:17:53
Product Available
C,4



Previously, I split the data into a Configuration Dataframe and Dataframes for each Product, where the Timestamp are set as index.
Thus, I could look up the Amount for each Product for each Configuration by doing this:
iloc_idx = product_A.index.get_indexer([configuration_timestamp], method='nearest')
It is not pretty, but works.
Now, the user can stage some actions and that leads to some events occurring simultaneously, which in turn breaks my index based idea.



Timestamp
Event
Data




25/07/2024  10:18:11
Product Available
C,2


25/07/2024  10:18:11
Product Available
B,1


25/07/2024  10:18:11
Configuration
A,B


25/07/2024  10:18:11
Configuration
B,C


25/07/2024  10:18:11
Product Available
B,3


25/07/2024  10:18:12
Product Available
A,1



data = {
    'Timestamp': ['25/07/2024  08:58:49', '25/07/2024  08:58:49', '25/07/2024  08:58:51', '25/07/2024  10:17:53', '25/07/2024  10:17:53', '25/07/2024  10:17:53', '25/07/2024  10:18:11', '25/07/2024  10:18:11', '25/07/2024  10:18:11', '25/07/2024  10:18:11', '25/07/2024  10:18:11', '25/07/2024  10:18:12'],
    'Event': ['Configuration', 'Product Available', 'Product Available', 'Product Available', 'Configuration', 'Product Available', 'Product Available', 'Product Available', 'Configuration', 'Configuration', 'Product Available', 'Product Available'],
    'Data': ['A,B', 'A,1', 'B,3', 'B,1', 'B,C', 'C,4', 'C,2','B,1','A,B','B,C','B,3','A,1']
} 

I can't sort the data based on the configuration, since there is an overlap in products, but I could combine them.
Is there a way to group my Data, so that I can see for each product the amount used?

Would you like to share what you have tried so far?

You would need to approach this in few steps:

Converting Timestamp to datetime

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M:%S')


Then seperating the configuration and product events

config_df = df[df['Event'] == 'Configuration'].copy()
product_df = df[df['Event'] == 'Product Available'].copy()


Then extracting product and amount from Data column in product_df

product_df[['Product', 'Amount']] = product_df['Data'].str.split(',', expand=True)
product_df['Amount'] = product_df['Amount'].astype(int)
product_df = product_df[['Timestamp', 'Product', 'Amount']]


Renaming and sorting both DataFrames by Timestamp

config_df = config_df.rename(columns={'Timestamp': 'Configuration_Timestamp'})
product_df = product_df.rename(columns={'Timestamp': 'Product_Timestamp'})

product_df = product_df.sort_values('Product_Timestamp')
config_df = config_df.sort_values('Configuration_Timestamp')


Merging product events with configuration events using Timestamp

merged_df = pd.merge_asof(product_df, 
                          config_df, 
                          left_on='Product_Timestamp', 
                          right_on='Configuration_Timestamp', 
                          direction='backward')


Displaying the result:

result_df = merged_df.groupby(['Configuration_Timestamp', 'Product'])['Amount'].sum().reset_index()
# Rename columns for clarity
result_df = result_df.rename(columns={'Amount': 'Total_Amount'})
print(result_df)

which will give you:




Timestamp
Product
Total_Amount




0
2024-07-25 08:58:49
A
1


1
2024-07-25 08:58:49
B
3


2
2024-07-25 10:17:53
B
1


3
2024-07-25 10:17:53
C
4


4
2024-07-25 10:18:11
A
1


5
2024-07-25 10:18:11
B
4


6
2024-07-25 10:18:11
C
2



